# View recycling cause view updated many times

Tags: android, listview

I have an andorid layout use to display a book object, including its name,author, and cover image.

However the information of the book maybe not complete, so I may need to load the book detail asynchronously, and once the book have a cover(the `book.icon` field), I will need to load the image too.

For example, at fist I got a book with its `name` and `detailLink` property, so I need to load the html document of the `detailLink`, and then parse the document to fill the `author` `icon` and `description` field and etc.

I use the `volley` library.

This is the `getView` of the adapter which use the `viewholder` pattern:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.common_dynamic_book, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.bName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
            viewHolder.bAuthor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
            viewHolder.bDescriptoin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_description);
            viewHolder.bImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Book bk = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.book = bk;

        setupViewHolder(viewHolder);

        if (bk.icon == null) {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(bk.detailLink, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String content) {
                    new ParseTask().execute(content, finalViewHolder);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                }
            });
            queue.add(request);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private void setupViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Book bk = viewHolder.book;
        viewHolder.bName.setText(bk.name);
        viewHolder.bAuthor.setText(bk.author);
        if (bk.description != null) {
//          viewHolder.bDescriptoin.setText(bk.description);
        }
        if (bk.icon != null && !bk.icon.equals("none")) {
            imageLoader.get(bk.icon, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
                    viewHolder.bImage.setImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ViewHolder> {
        @Override
        protected ViewHolder doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            String content = (String) objects[0];
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) objects[1];

            parser.buildBook(content, viewHolder.book);  //parse the html document, and fill the book object with information
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            setupViewHolder(viewHolder);
        }
    }
```

Everything looks fine, however I meet a problem:

When I scolle the listview quickly(like a fling gesture), I  will find that a view may be updated so many times.

For example, at first the adapter have 10 books whose detail are not loaded. And the book name are `Book1` `Book2` .... `Book10`.

Then backgournd process will start to load the book, once I fling the listview from top to bottom, I will find that one list item will be updated many times. For example, it show the name `Book8`(without further information) at first, then change to (`Book4` with loaded detail info) and then maybe another book with loaded info, **AND FINALLY** it display the `Book8` with loaded informaiton.

It seems that this is caused by the view recycling. I wonder if it is possible to void this?

---

Update:

I think this is caused by the view recycling, for exmaple, a view first are bound to `Book4`, and the background load task start ,then when I scroll the listview, android reuse this view to display the item `Book8`, at the moment the request for `Book4` arrived, and the view are updated to `Book4`, then the `Book8` task completed, and the view is updated again. I think this is the problem, but I do not know how to fix it...

Comment: do you want it to load the HTMl only once?

Comment: The html is loaded only once right now.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you using [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/), as it automatically caches images for you and has a nice implementation for large image datasets, which is your case !

They have also in their samples, an example which is similar to what you should implement:
[SampleListDetailAdapter](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SampleListDetailAdapter.java)

Hope it helps !

Comment: You may misunderstand me, in fact, I do not load image only, the book detail information are also re-updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the url with your `ViewHolder`.

```
private static class ViewHolder {
   // Your members

   String url;
}
```

The getView method:

```
getView(..) {

        Book bk = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.book = bk;

        // Do not recreate view if it is the same view
        if (bk.icon != null && viewHolder.url != null && viewHolder.url.equals(bk.detailLink))
           return convertView;

        viewHolder.url = bk.detailLink;
}
```

And when you are getting a response:

```
if (bk.icon != null && !bk.icon.equals("none")) {
                imageLoader.get(bk.icon, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {

                        if (!imageContainer.getUrl().equals(viewHolder.url))
                            return;

                        viewHolder.bImage.setImageBitmap(imageContainer.getBitmap());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    }
                });
            }
```